# Is there a way to take exclusive control of the keyboard and mouse in a Qt Quick application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-quick, qt6

I'm attempting to write a program in Qt Quick that implements remote desktop functionality as part of it. One thing that would be helpful is to be able to take exclusive control of the keyboard so that, for instance, pressing Alt+F4 causes a window on the server to be closed rather than closing the remote desktop app itself. Being able to take exclusive control of the mouse would also be handy but isn't strictly necessary.

When using QWidgets, there's functions like grabKeyboard() and grabMouse() that seem like they would do what I want, but I don't see any equivalent functionality in Qt Quick. Is this even possible, and if so, how would it be done?

(please note, my application has to compile on both Qt5 and Qt6 so if two different strategies are needed depending on the Qt version, I'd like to know both.)

Comment: I believe this will be OS dependent and not a Qt feature.

Comment: You probably need to implement and register your own class in C++ to do it from QML. Not difficult.